# Add data to specific subplot

Tags: matlab, plot, figure, subplot

Suppose I have 2 figures and in each one I have 3x3 subplot matrix.

The code looks like:

```
figure(1)
subplot(3,3,1)
plot(...)
subplot(3,3,2)
plot(...)
subplot(3,3,3)
plot(...)
subplot(3,3,4)
plot(...)
and so on
```

Some Calculations

```
figure(2)
subplot(3,3,1)
plot(...)
subplot(3,3,2)
plot(...)
subplot(3,3,3)
plot(...)
subplot(3,3,4)
plot(...)
and so on
```

and here I have more calculations.

Now, I had like to insert inside subplot(3,3,4) in figure(2) the (x,y) I had just calculated in the end.

I guess a solution would be to plot the graphs after all of the calculations but in case I dont want to change the order, how can I do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the `subplot` command in any order. At any point in the code, if you want to only plot something on the `m`-th block of `figure(n)`, just do:

```
figure(n);
subplot(3,3,m);
plot(...)
```

All existing plots in other blocks will remain unchanged.